# Changing value of list box dynamically when selecting values from combo box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have a combo box which gets data from a database and a list box which also gets data from a database.

Now what I'd like to do is change the value on the list box depending on the value of the combo box.

For example of if I select “apple” from a combo box, then in the list it should display the types of apples.

In this case let’s say the types of apples are Granny Smith, Red Delicious, and so on. I hope you guys get what I am trying to say. I have not started to code but I need a method that will allow me to get the desired output. And also I am new to asp.net with vb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Dim com As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT type FROM Tbl WHERE category = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'", sqlConn)
    Dim sql As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

    While sql.Read
        ListBox1.Items.Add(sql.GetString(0))
    End While
    sql.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: i cant even get a message under `Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Its a event handler. It executes the code when the event occurs, in this case when the selected item in the `ComboBox` changes. `ComboBox1` must be the control you want to monitorize.

Answer (score 1):

Use **OnSelectedIndexChanged** function of the **ComboBox**. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.onselectedindexchanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 and then retrieve the values for the **ListBox** from the database.